# Why can't an object have a companion object?

Tags: kotlin, companion-object

I have an `object` for my tests using `Spek`

```kotlin
object CodeTest : Spek({
  describe ("feature1") {
    it("has correct code") {
      assertTrue(123, 120 + 3)
    }
  }
})
```

I would like to initialize some constants.

I can't just dump the constants into the body of the `CodeTest`:

```kotlin
object CodeTest : Spek({
  describe ("feature1") {
    it("has correct code") {
      assertTrue(ALL_GOOD, 120 + 3)
    }
  }
}) {
  private const val = ALL_GOOD = 123
}
```

Because they won't be available for use in the scope in which I want to use them. The solution for a class, and a very straight forward solution overall, would be to use a companion object:

```kotlin
object CodeTest : Spek({
  describe ("feature1") {
    it("has correct code") {
      assertTrue(ALL_GOOD, 120 + 3)
    }
  }
}) {
  companion object Codes {
    private const val ALL_GOOD = 123
  }
}
```

However the compiler informs me that I can't add a companion object to another object.  So ok, I can change my object to a class, problem solved I guess.

But it still is a singleton.  And I don't see any way that a companion object can ever make an object *not* a singleton.  So why is this restriction in place?  Why must it be a class in order for it to have a companion object?

Comment: Why would an object need a companion object itself. just place anything you'd put in the companion object in the object itself.
A companion object of a class is the set of its "singleton" members/data, an object is already a singleton.

Comment: @al3c If you put them into the object they will not be accessible from the scope where I am using them in the example.  I'll clarify this in the question.

Comment: I know nothing of `Spek`, however why do you define `objects`? seems you could just use a variable `val codeTest = Spek(/*whatever*/)` at that point you can just define the contant on the same level.
If you truly need more encapsulation you can wrap that in a `fun`: `fun test(): Spek { val C = 123; return Spek(..) }`

Comment: With your second example use `import CodeTest.ALL_GOOD` or `assertTrue(CodeTest.ALL_GOOD, 120 + 3)`

Comment: @al3c Most my colleagues are former Java devs so that's just how they feel comfortable doing things.  Your fix might work, but I'm not really looking for work-arounds right now.  Changing to `class` seems to be fine.  The question here really is just "Why doesn't Kotlin let objects have companion objects?"

Comment: If you aren't very concerned about compile-time constants, you can define them in the lambda itself. But if you are you can define object inside instead of companion objects there.

Comment: @ÉamonnOlive The reason for not having a companion object inside of an object is that the companion obejct is a singleton object associated with a class. An object is already a singleton hence it doesn't need any singleton counterpart. Nonetheless note that you can have an object inside an object, which might be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Companion objects are not exactly analogous to what a class object is (the static members of a class) in Java. For the use case you're describing, the typical way to organize your code would be to define a top-level property/constant outside the class definition, private to the file.

```
private const val ALL_GOOD = 123

object CodeTest : Spek({
  describe ("feature1") {
    it("has correct code") {
      assertTrue(ALL_GOOD, 120 + 3)
    }
  }
})
```

Even if your class was a `class` and not an `object`, I would still do it this way for private constants. There's no need for instantiating a singleton if it's solely to store some constants.